# C# Event Handler Delegate Returns Null

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am trying to return a value when a grid cell has been double clicked.   Here is my code for setting up my delegate and event handler:

```
   public class SelectedItemEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string SelectedChoice { get; set; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectedItemEventArgs> ItemHasBeenSelected;
```

Here is my code for setting up the double click:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = ItemHasBeenSelected;

        if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs
                { SelectedChoice = txtCustomer.Text.ToString() });
            }
    }
```

Handler is always null.   If I change the event handler code to this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        var handler = ItemHasBeenSelected;
        string choice = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].ToString();
        if (choice != null)
        {
            handler(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs
            { SelectedChoice = choice});
        }
   }
```

I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   I did see this:  [C# Delegate returns back NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833197/c-sharp-delegate-returns-back-null)  but I couldn't figure out how it worked.  I ultimately want the value of dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex] returned.

Comment: if (handler != null) handler(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs { SelectedChoice = choice });

Comment: Have you added method into the event `ItemHasBeenSelected`? Otherwise it stays null.

Comment: if (handler != null) handler(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs { SelectedChoice = choice });   --- thank you for this but the handler is always null.   How would you add a method into the event ItemHasBeenSelected?  Just put a body{} and this dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].ToString();  as return text?

Comment: Did you hook anything up to the event? Do you somewhere have `something.ItemHasBeenSelected += Method;` ?

Comment: Thanks to Tommy's answer, I did hook up the Load and the ItemHasBeenSelected methods.  I am still not getting the correct return value.  When I try to add this set { SelectedChoice = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex]; } to my SelectedChoice property, I get an error because e does not exist in current context and an object reference is required for dataGridView1.

Comment: When I just set SelectedChoice to "X", I get "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure method is added into event before calling event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ItemHasBeenSelected += Form1_ItemHasBeenSelected;
}

private void Form1_ItemHasBeenSelected(object sender, SelectedItemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Chosen: " + e.SelectedChoice);
}
```

However, event is in fact for loosely coupling.

If everything is under your control, just directly call a method and save yourself from events.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  When I do this, I get "Chosen:  dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex"  Like I get the actual text and not the value in the text.   The main thing I am trying to do is the put up a user control and return the value in grid column 0 when the user double clicks it.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I needed to do this:  string choice = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); in my dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick method

Comment: Actually, it didn't return the value to the calling program.  All it did was display it on the screen -- which was good because I got the value but bad because I can't figure out how to return it.